# Which module contains the given class

Tags: command-line-interface, simics

Using simics cli, once I know the class of the object, how can I get the name of the module that contains the class? Or should I consult something other than the cli?

Example: object `qsp.mb.nb` is of class `northbridge_x58`. Which module includes `northbridge_x58`?

And how to get the path to the `.so` of the module?

I tried `list-objects` and `list-classes` with various flags and looking up the documentation of the class. Still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `-v` should add the path to the .SO file.

Using `help northbridge_x58` provide more info, including a "Provided By" section.

A useful command when searching for some hard-to-find matter is `apropos`, or `a` for short.

BR Simon

#IAmIntel